Topology generated by seminorm, why not just take supremum

Let $\{p_{a}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ be a family of seminorms on the vector space on the vector space $\mathcal{X}$, the canonical definition of the topology generated by these seminorms is the topology generated by the set $\{ y \in X| p_\alpha  (y-x)<\epsilon\}_{x \in \mathcal{ X}, \alpha \in A, \epsilon >0}$

I wonder instead of defining the topology like this, why not define the topology simply by taking the supremum of the seminorms, especially when all $p_{\alpha}$ are indeed norms, the supremum $p(x) := \sup_{\alpha\in A} p_{\alpha}(x)$ is a norm as well, and similarly in the case of a seminorm.
It seems to have nice properties such as in the definition of convergence. So why don't we define it like this? Is there any relationship between such topology defined by the supremum vs the canonical definition?

Perhaps the $\sup$ could be $\infty$.

The comment of copper.hat shows the core of the problem. I think a nice example which illustrate this is the vector space of all entire functions $H(\mathbb{C})$ with the compact open topology generated by the family of norms $\{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$
$$
p_n(f)=\max_{|z| \le n} |f(z)|.
$$
Note that each $p_n$ is indeed a norm by the identity theorem. A function $f \in H(\mathbb{C})$ with $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} p_n(f) <  \infty$ would be bounded on $\mathbb{C}$, hence constant by Liouville's theorem.
For a second example consider the sequence space of all bounded sequences $l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ and the family of semi-norms $\{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $p_n(x)=|x_n|$ $(x=(x_1,x_2,\dots))$. Here $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} p_n(x) <  \infty$ always exists and is the supremum norm. However, the topologies are different. For example the sequence $(e_k)$ with $e_k=(\delta_{jk})_j$ is divergent with respect to the supremum norm but convergent to $(0)$ with respect to the topology generated by $\{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.
